# KnockoutJs Observable Arrays and Dropdownlists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm new to KnockoutJs and I wonder if anyone can help with this.

I have a viewmodel, populated from a Mvc3 controller, bound to a dropdown and this is working fine.

I have additional data stored in the "platforms" observableArray, and
I would like this data to be displayed in textboxes, dependant on the 
selected value in the dropdown.

Here is my code so far:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sampleSubmission = function () {
            this.selectedPlatform = ko.observable();
            this.platforms = ko.observableArray();

            this.showSearch = ko.observable(false);
            this.craftText = ko.observable();
            this.showSerialNumber = ko.observable(0);

            this.selectedPlatform.subscribe(function (platformId) {





            } .bind(this));
        };

        var sampleSubmissionViewModel = new sampleSubmission();
        ko.applyBindings(sampleSubmissionViewModel);

        //Load the platforms
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPlatforms", "Home")',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                sampleSubmissionViewModel.platforms(data);
            }
        });
    });  

</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind the dropdown list's value to the selectedPlatform, like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: platforms, value: selectedPlatform, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

I modified your code and took some best guesses at what you wanted to do and created a sample.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/DVXH7/

Comment: Thanks very much, John. That worked a treat. Thanks very much for your quick reply.

Comment: No problem. Just in case ... notice that the objects inside of the observableArray platforms are not observables. For this sample it was not needed, but if you wanted them to be observables, you'd likely want to create a Platform constructor object and make its properties observables. That is only necessary if you want those properties to have change notifications.    Let me know if you want to see that too.